# Newbie Android menu question

Tags: android, xml, menu

I'm an android noob creating my first menu.     In the New Android XML file dialog there is a list of "**Available Qualifiers**" to choose from. What are these and what do they do regarding menus?

BTW I did a Google search for *"available qualifiers" "New Android XML File"*  and got only 5 hits- only 3 in English and none of them helpful.   On StackOverflow there were no hits on "available qualifiers".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, you don't need them.

The available qualifiers are shown when you create any new XML file.

They are here to help you name and locate your files.

For example when you create a layout, you can choose the "orientation", so that you will have one layout for the landscape view, and one for the portrait view.

The layout will be automatically chosen whether you are holding the phone in portrait or landscape mode.

This is also useful when you are creating a new language file, to define which language you are going to use.

Comment: Is there a comprehensive list in some Android documentation about what each of the qualifiers means and does?  Thanks in advance for further clarification.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules

Comment: Would you mind ticking the answer if this was what you looked for?

Answer (score 1):

The 'New Android XML' is used to create resouce xml, it has nothing to do with creating menu.

See [this tutorial](http://androidappdocs.appspot.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) about how to create menus.

Comment: A menu XML file   IS   a resource XML file.   It lives in ...res\menu

Comment: ... plus Menu is one of the selectable options when you use the New Android XML File dialog, which is the dialog we're talking about.  In fact Menu is pre-selected if you invoke that dialog from the menu folder.

Comment: Right! There is a menu folder, I forgot. Sorry